# Mysql C++ Connector Crash Issues

Tags: c++, mysql

Team,

I am trying to use mysqlclient version 16 and Mysql c++ connector to connect to the Mysql database and perform some DB operations. The code for our product relying on these libraries is already written. Mysql Server version  5.1.56. I could see that it is crashing at various occasions.

Below are few crash dumps. Any idea why these are happening? Typically during close connection and create connection.

1. For close connection, Iam using mSqlCon->close()
2. For create connection iam using some thing like below:

   driver = get_driver_instance();
   mSqlCon = driver->connect( connection_properties );

mSqlCon is of type sql::Connection *. Any help is appreciated!!

```
#0  0x00007f82b4f064ff in ?? () from /usr/local/lib64/mysql/libmysqlclient.so.16
#1  0x00007f82b4f06758 in net_real_write () from /usr/local/lib64/mysql/libmysqlclient.so.16
#2  0x00007f82b4f06c3b in net_flush () from /usr/local/lib64/mysql/libmysqlclient.so.16
#3  0x00007f82b4f03279 in mysql_real_connect () from /usr/local/lib64/mysql/libmysqlclient.so.16
#4  0x00007f82b4a630d7 in sql::mysql::NativeAPI::LibmysqlStaticProxy::real_connect (this=, mysql=0x7f82ac041680, 
    host=0x7f82ac053d80 "K", user=0x4f , passwd=0x0, db=0x35a5d367fc14006c , 
    port=3306, unix_socket=0x7f82ac041680 "\a", client_flag=140199208425088)
    at /export/home2/tmp/cteam/bs/connector-c++-64bit/src/mysql-connector-c++-1.1.1/driver/nativeapi/libmysql_static_proxy.cpp:316
#5  0x00007f82b4a649a9 in sql::mysql::NativeAPI::MySQL_NativeConnectionWrapper::connect (this=0x7f82ac0d22d0, host=, 
    user=, passwd=, db=, port=, socket_or_pipe=..., 
    client_flag=140199208425088) at /build/cteam/bs/linux-x86_64/connector-common-alt-64bit/boost/include/boost-1_39/boost/smart_ptr/shared_ptr.hpp:408
#6  0x00007f82b49f8ebe in sql::mysql::MySQL_Connection::init (this=0x7f82ac0d3740, properties=...)
    at /export/home2/tmp/cteam/bs/connector-c++-64bit/src/mysql-connector-c++-1.1.1/driver/mysql_uri.h:51
#7  0x00007f82b49f57b3 in MySQL_Connection (this=0x7f82ac0d3740, _driver=, _proxy=, properties=...)
    at /export/home2/tmp/cteam/bs/connector-c++-64bit/src/mysql-connector-c++-1.1.1/driver/mysql_connection.cpp:141
#8  0x00007f82b4a062cd in sql::mysql::MySQL_Driver::connect (this=0x7f82ac0466e0, properties=...)
    at /build/cteam/bs/linux-x86_64/connector-common-alt-64bit/boost/include/boost-1_39/boost/smart_ptr/scoped_ptr.hpp:96
```

```
#0  0x00007fbf785e7745 in free () from /lib64/libc.so.6
#1  0x00007fbf79b49224 in __gnu_cxx::new_allocator::deallocate (this=, 
    __nstart=0x7fbf740dbc76, __nfinish=0x7fbf740dbc80) at /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/3.4.6/../../../../include/c++/3.4.6/ext/new_allocator.h:86
#2  std::_Deque_base >::_M_deallocate_node (
    this=, __nstart=0x7fbf740dbc76, __nfinish=0x7fbf740dbc80)
    at /export/home2/tmp/cteam/bs/connector-c++-64bit/src/mysql-connector-c++-1.1.1/driver/mysql_debug.cpp:401
#3  std::_Deque_base >::_M_destroy_nodes (
    this=, __nstart=0x7fbf740dbc76, __nfinish=0x7fbf740dbc80)
    at /export/home2/tmp/cteam/bs/connector-c++-64bit/src/mysql-connector-c++-1.1.1/driver/mysql_debug.cpp:497
#4  0x00007fbf79b491d0 in ~_Deque_base (this=0x7fbf74049db00000, __in_chrg=)
    at /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/3.4.6/../../../../include/c++/3.4.6/bits/stl_deque.h:425
#5  0x00007fbf79b48def in ~MySQL_DebugLogger (this=0x7fbf740444d0, __in_chrg=)
    at /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/3.4.6/../../../../include/c++/3.4.6/bits/stl_deque.h:703
#6  0x00007fbf79b4829f in checked_delete (this=)
    at /build/cteam/bs/linux-x86_64/connector-common-alt-64bit/boost/include/boost-1_39/boost/checked_delete.hpp:34
#7  boost::detail::sp_counted_impl_p::dispose (this=)
    at /build/cteam/bs/linux-x86_64/connector-common-alt-64bit/boost/include/boost-1_39/boost/smart_ptr/detail/sp_counted_impl.hpp:78
#8  0x00007fbf79b3ae22 in ~MySQL_ConnectionData (this=0x7fbf740d6140, __in_chrg=)
    at /build/cteam/bs/linux-x86_64/connector-common-alt-64bit/boost/include/boost-1_39/boost/smart_ptr/detail/sp_counted_base_gcc_x86.hpp:145
#9  ~MySQL_Connection (this=0x7fbf740d6140, __in_chrg=)
    at /export/home2/tmp/cteam/bs/connector-c++-64bit/src/mysql-connector-c++-1.1.1/driver/mysql_connection.cpp:162
```

Comment: I imagine that you might have a memory corruption in your code. Consider compiling all of it with `g++ -Wall -g`, improve your code till no warnings are given, and use `valgrind` and `gdb` to debug it.

Comment: Also, it looks like you are using some very ancient 3.4.6 version of the GCC compiler `g++`; current version of GCC is 4.7 and is much better (more efficient, more standard conformant). Please **upgrade your compiler** ro at least GCC 4.6, preferably 4.7 (and your *stdc++* library)

Comment: One thing to note here is that there no warnings. We take every warning and fixed it. The linking with connector is static in my code and no warnings thrown after linking and executing it. It works some times and some times it crashes weirdly.

Comment: @Santhosh, do you have a crashing scenario? Can you successfully replicate the crash? Most likely it is the memory corruption and so, like Basile said, valgrind is your friend.

Comment: Please paste a block of the code. Otherwise we can only use our imagination to figure out what your code does. There are many ways you can make an error and no good answer can be given without the code itself.